# Not able to clear Javascript Memoized function cache

Tags: javascript, memoization

I am trying to clear the memoized cache object but tried different solutions like prototype, call and bind but not able to make it work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function memoize(func) {
  let cache = {};
  return function() {
    function clear() { cache = {}; }
    const key = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    if(cache[key]) { return cache[key]; }
    const result = func.apply(this, arguments);
    cache[key] = result;
    return result;
  }
}

function square(num) {
  console.log('calling square of', num);
  return num*num;
}

const memoizedSquare = memoize(square);

memoizedSquare(1);
memoizedSquare(1);
memoizedSquare(2);
memoizedSquare.clear(); // getting error on this line
memoizedSquare(2);
memoizedSquare(3);

function addition(a,b,c,d) {
  console.log('calling addition of', a,b,c,d);
  return a+b+c+d;
}

const memoizedAddition = memoize(addition);

memoizedAddition(1,2,3,4);
memoizedAddition(1,2,3,4);
memoizedAddition(4,2,3,1);
memoizedAddition(6,7,8,9);
memoizedAddition(6,7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `memoizedSquare.clear()` to work, the function that you return from `memoize()` should have a `clear` property added to it. At the moment, your code declares the `clear()` function inside of the returned function, but isn't accessible to your calling code as it isn't exposed in any way. Since functions are objects in JavaScript, you can add a property to it just like you would with an ordinary object with [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#dot_notation), for example:

```js
function memoize(func) {
  let cache = {};
  function fn() {
    const key = JSON.stringify(arguments);
    if(cache[key]) { return cache[key]; }
    const result = func.apply(this, arguments);
    cache[key] = result;
    return result;
  }
  
  fn.clear = function() { cache = {}; }
  return fn;
}

function square(num) {
  console.log('calling square of', num);
  return num*num;
}

const memoizedSquare = memoize(square);

console.log(memoizedSquare(1));
console.log(memoizedSquare(1));
console.log(memoizedSquare(2));
memoizedSquare.clear(); // getting error on this line
console.log(memoizedSquare(2));
console.log(memoizedSquare(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, and probably better, design would be to return a pair `memoized, clear`:

```js
function memoize(func) {
    let cache = {};

    return [
        (...args) => {
            const key = JSON.stringify(args)
            return cache[key] ?? (cache[key] = func.apply(this, args))
        },
        () => { cache = {} }
    ]
}

function square(num) {
    console.log('calling square of', num);
    return num*num;
}

const [memoizedSquare, clearIt] = memoize(square);

console.log(memoizedSquare(1));
console.log(memoizedSquare(1));
console.log(memoizedSquare(2));
clearIt()
console.log(memoizedSquare(2));
console.log(memoizedSquare(2));
```